# How to use Enter Block to push agents into system?

Tags: anylogic

I have tried the following method. See Image

[image]

My initial stock size is 5000. And I have called a function to push new agents into the system. But when I run the model, the system is empty of agents.

What is missing here?

[image]

Comment: where are you calling the feedFunction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually call the `feedFunction`, else the code is never executed.

Write it "on startup" of `Main` and you will be good:
[image]

You can always test if code was actually executed by adding a `traceln("executed");` into the code, if you like